# Halal marriage and sex for non muslims

Tags: halal-haram

If you are non -muslim but now following halal marriage and sex guidelines and islam teachings on marriage how much could you be considered muslim?

Comment: Not more than before marriage

Answer (score 1):

Islam is a religion, not just a way or guidelines for marriage and sex.
I'm not sure I understood your question but if you did not convert to islam, "following halal marriage and sex guidelines and islam teachings on marriage" does not make you a muslim.